# How to get JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

I wanted to see the memory consumption of already running java program.

If i write a program to get `Runtime.freeMemory()`, this program will run under new JVM.

How to get already running Java program's JVM and run  `Runtime.freeMemory()`?

Comment: A profiler can help you out.

Comment: @Rajkumar Seenappa go for tools available like [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/)

Comment: You could attach to your running programm with jvisualvm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html). It accesses local or remote (if enabled) JVMs and provides various options to graphically monitor memory usage and threads. Many similar tools (command line or graphical) also exist if this one does not suit your needs.